# Counter Button with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm a beginner at learning reactjs, I'm making a small app, it's only to write posts and I want to make a like button and counter for each post, I tried to make it using state but it uses the same counter for all posts
here's MyPosts.jsx file

```
import React from 'react'

export default (props) => {
let likes=0;
return <div className="Post">
  <h4>{props.post} </h4>
  <p>{props.like}</p>
  <button onClick={() =>props.LikesCount(props.like)}>Like</button>
  <button onClick={()=>props.deletePost(props.index)} >Delete</button>
</div>
}
export const Post = () => {
return <div>
   post export

</div>
}
```

and the function to count the likes and the state from the app.js file

```
   state = {
    like:0,
    posts: []
}
  LikesCount = (like) => {

    this.setState({ like: this.state.like + 1})
  }
```

any idea how to make a counter for each post without using the state? Thank you.

Comment: is `LikesCount` being passed as a prop somewhere?

Comment: You could use an SQL database to store the likes count

Comment: @ewizard yes on app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the issue with your code is that you are using 1 `like` variable whereas posts is an array. I am assuming that `deletePost(some index)` is deleting the post with some positive index from `posts` array.

### Solution 1

You can convert the `likes` in the state to an array. So, when you do `props.LikesCount(props.index)` and inside the `LikesCount` function,

```
LikesCount = (index) => {

    this.state.likes[index] += 1;
  }
```

And now when you delete a post, you need to also splice the same index in `likes` array.

### Solution 2

You can make `posts` an array of objects where each object represents this:

```
{
   likes: 0,
   post: ''
}
```

Comment: Great! Please make this an official solution for this. :)